# Server Online Player Count Ping PHP

Tags: php, ping

so I got this code together to ping the Online Player Count/Max Player Slots for my server. I think I've got everything done correctly, but this error occurs...any suggestions on how to fix it?
Here is the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u7335206/public_html/mc-vr.com/pc.php on line 21

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require "MinecraftQuery.class.php";

// Variables for each of your servers: 
$server_info = array();

try 
{
// Getting Server Info:
$query = new MinecraftQuery();
$query->Connect("192.99.14.177", 25573);
$server_info = $query->GetInfo();
} 
catch(MinecraftQueryException $e) 
{
// Getting the information failed.
}

try 
{
<?php if ($server_info) { ?>
<p><span style='font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;'><font       color='#FFFFFF'><?= $server_info["numplayers"] ?>/<?= $server_info["maxplayers"] ?></font></span></p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p><span style='font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;'><font   color='#FFFFFF'>0/120</span></font></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
try 
{
<?php if ($server_info) { ?>
```

to

```
try 
{
if ($server_info) { ?>
```

---

You are also missing your closing bracket for the `try`. But since you are not doing a `catch()`, just remove the `try`

```
<?php
require "MinecraftQuery.class.php";

// Variables for each of your servers: 
$server_info = array();

try 
{
// Getting Server Info:
$query = new MinecraftQuery();
$query->Connect("192.99.14.177", 25573);
$server_info = $query->GetInfo();
} 
catch(MinecraftQueryException $e) 
{
// Getting the information failed.
}

if ($server_info) { ?>
<p><span style='font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;'><font       color='#FFFFFF'><?= $server_info["numplayers"] ?>/<?= $server_info["maxplayers"] ?></font></span></p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p><span style='font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none;'><font   color='#FFFFFF'>0/120</span></font></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives me this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/u7335206/public_html/mc-vr.com/pc.php on line 25

Comment: You are also missing your closing bracket for the `try`. Change the last line to  `<?php } } ?>`

Comment: Hmm still gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting catch (T_CATCH) in /home/u7335206/public_html/mc-vr.com/pc.php on line 25

Comment: when using `try {..}` you must have a `catch(...){ ...}`. Since it is already in an `if ($server_info)` just remove the `try{`.